# Java how to get max byte array size that will fit the vm limit

Tags: java, arrays, byte

How can I find the maximum byte array size that will not exceed the VM limit?

What I tried is:

```
int size = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
byte[] request = new byte[size];
```

But then I get the error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit`

The backstory is my packet proxy keeps missing parts of a packet because I don't know what the max memory size I can use is.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to mention, you get all kinds of GC related problems with those large arrays, especially if you allocate them dynamically. When you create a few managed ones at program start, it might be safe. But then again alternatives like off heap ByteBuffers could be better.

Comment: Give it up!!  You should not intentionally try to create a ginormous array that occupies most of available heap.  There are too many ways for this to come back and  bite you.

Comment: And no valid comm protocol should require that you allocate enormous buffers.

Comment: And keep in mind that there are probably many Java implementations where you cannot create a byte array of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements, regardless of how much heap is free, since the max object size is, at most, that value, and the object needs at least 16, probably 32 bytes for its "header".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find out the answer to your question yourself with something like

```
long maxByteArraySize() {
   long size = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
   while(--size > 0) try {
        new byte[size];
        break;
   } catch(Throwable t) {}   
   return size;
}
```

Also note, that you can increase the amount of memory available to the jvm with `-Xmx` flag, eg: `java -Xmx4g MyClass` will probably let you allocate (a lot) larger array than you are getting by default.

(Not that I think that what you are trying to do is actually a great idea ...)

Answer (score 0):

Well `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `2,147,483,647`; you can determine how much memory is free with

```
System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
```

But I wouldn't try and allocate all of it to a `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `arrays` are considered to be objects in java. And objects are stored on `heap memory`. It doesn't matter whether your objects are *local objects* but only its references are stored in `stack memory`. You can find the `max heap size` by following :-

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version 2>&1 | findstr MaxHeapSize
```

And approximately take less size array.